# What's the proper American English and British English word for the wind shield used on beaches?

Tags: nouns

In England, the beaches can be windy.  I have seen people put up a "wind shield" like this. [image: picture of beach with vertically arranged cloth hung to block the wind]

I haven't seen people use this in America or Europe, but I haven't been to many beaches there.

I'd call this wind shield, simply because it shields the wind.  But in America,
windshield means the frontal glass of a car.

Is there a more proper name for this in British English, American English
and other English (South African, Australian, etc)?

Thank you

Comment: What did you google to find  that image? Anyway, as two words, "wind shield" wouldn't cause any problems to a (my) American ear. Though we might call it a "wind *screen*" . That said, I haven't seen those used on any beaches here in the NE US.

Comment: 'Wind break' is the normal BrE term.

Comment: Yep, turns out they're listed as "beach [*windscreens*](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/s/ref=is_s_ss_i_0_9?k=beach+windscreen&sprefix=beach+win)" on Amazon.

Comment: @Edwin, what's the plural? Can you buy "two *windbreaks*" (+s)? I ask because here a "*windbreaker*" (+er) is a kind of light jacket.

Comment: RHKWebster's has the best definition at freedictionary: windbreak 
n. a growth of trees, a structure of boards, or the like serving as a shelter from the wind. Yes, it's a count noun. [Here](http://www.riverswayleisure.co.uk/acatalog/Windbreaks.html?gclid=CLiwhbCEvMACFbPJtAodckMAOA) is an ad; the ones I've used for 55 years are made from the same material as our deckchairs.

Comment: ... We used to have lightish jackets called 'windcheaters'. We probably still do, but the name has changed.

Comment: @DanBron In the Uk a windscreen is.... the front glass of a car.

Comment: I agree with Edwin. In BrE it is a wind break.  http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/3402760.htm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both my (English) parents and I refer to them as 'wind-breaks'. Windshield like its namesake on a car sounds American. In England cars have windscreens. Windshelter would be fine as that is exactly what you'd be doing on a British beach!

Comment: +1 All my (native British English speakers) would refer to them as "wind-breaks" and that is the term I have heard overwhelmingly more than any other on British beaches.

Comment: Precisely. Note the category name; http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Browse/ID72/33010851/c_1/1%7Ccategory_root%7CSports+and+leisure%7C33006346/c_2/2%7C33006346%7CCamping+and+caravanning%7C33007546/c_3/3%7Ccat_33007546%7CShelters+and+wind+breaks%7C33010851.htm

Comment: Thank you. This also makes sense, because there's no ambiguity between windshield, windscreen, windbreak, windbreaker and windshelter.

Answer (score 13):

[Portable Windscreen](http://www.marthastewart.com/268280/portable-windscreen), as advertised at MarthaStewart.com.

Since Martha Stewart is a U.S. business woman with an eponymous U.S. business, I suspect this is what it's being called in the U.S.

[image: Screenshot from (US) MarthaStewart.com calling it "Portable Windscreen"]

Other terms at [Amazon.com in the U.K](http://www.amazon.co.uk/ABO-Windshield-Portable-Beach-Screen/sim/B000VGVSNQ/2). call it a windscreen, windbreak, windbreaker, and... windshield.

[image: Screenshot from UK Amazon calling it "Windscreen", "Windbreak", "Windbreaker", and "Windshield"]

Comment: But how often do people call things by the stodgy sounding name used by the seller?

Comment: @djechlin At least as often as they go to buy it, unless they're in no hurry and both the buyer and the seller are patient.

Comment: Amazon is a bit misleading because they go out of their way to find synonyms

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure people just call them what they look like. "Easel" comes from the Dutch word for "donkey", because at some time someone thought it was sort of like a donkey for a painting. Wind break, block, shield? all acceptable. Probably regional as a result.

My rigorous research:

[image: wind beach google search results]

As an aside, I don't get why people go to the beach when it's so miserable you have to bring these things with you.

Comment: A large number of people who buy these don't actually go to the beach. They remain the the car park _next_ to the beach (I used to live near a particularly busy beach with a grassy car park).

Comment: Going to the beach in England isn't supposed to be a pleasurable experience - it's an exercise in endurance! ;-)

Comment: Many people have to book holidays in advance, so don't get to pick the weather.

Comment: Not only can one not always avoid a windy period, it's often the case that out of the wind, it's actually quite pleasantly warm and sunny.

Answer (score 0):

They are not so common in the US, so there is not going to be a single, unambiguous term. Walking along the ocean in Cornwall, every little beach had someone selling or renting these, and everyone was out there pounding in stakes. In the US? You sometimes see things more like tents with a wall missing, or umbrellas that adapt to having one edge in the sand, but not these.

So, if you are writing fiction, you might reconsider writing this on a US beach at all. If you're just writing for a US audience, plan to explain and describe it.